# Varchar to Decimal cast returns '0'

Tags: mysql, sum, decimal, varchar

After loading a .csv file,  I want to convert a VARCHAR (50) column ('gross_unit_price')  which contains various positive and negative decimal numbers (eg. -165.65 or 245 etc..) to DECIMAL (10,2) in order to apply various functions.

The original .csv is encoded in UCS-2 LE BOM.

The query below returns '0.00' instead of the actual decimal numbers.

> SELECT CAST(gross_unit_price AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS RESULT
>   FROM  `vbq-sales`

Comment: mmmhh.. why is your column that contains only decimal numbers a varchar ?

Comment: because otherwise, the data don't load with the correct information.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your loading procedure.

Comment: I don't know why someone upvoted " the data don't load...." data types exist for a reason.

Comment: Did you load it into a table declared UCS2?  Or did you convert as you loaded?  (Let's see the `LOAD` command.)

Comment: Next time, have the table be utf8, but the `LOAD` say `ucs2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK folks I found the answer: the original file is encoded UCS2. So I had to re-encode to UTF8 and then the functions worked.

Thank you for helping me find the solution. Barmar and Rick.